# How to close a background thread in a service when the service get destroyed

Tags: android, android-service, java-threads

I want to close a background thread in my service in the `onDestroy` method, because if I stop my service the background thread is still running. Because `thread.stop()` is deprecated, I don't really know how to do it.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    runAsForeground();

    Runnable service = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            connect(client,options);

        }
    };

    backgroundThread = new Thread(service);
    backgroundThread.start();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand methode called");

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Show me your connect method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread life cycle is not the same as Android Context Component life cycle. Stopping the service is not enough to stop the thread which service created. [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#interrupt()) is a option. - You should catch `InterruptedException` though. If it is not enough, you can check if service is not stopped inside your `connect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a `Service`. Then you can `Context.stopService(intent)` just the same way you `Context.startService(intent)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
```

It will stop this service and all its `Threads`.